# Compiler constants, optimizations, and performance

Tags: c#, .net

I have a chunk of code that frequently needs tracing information output so that clients can help debug the output - it's very math oriented.

I definitely don't want the tracing to be enabled in production for performance reasons, but having to comment it in and out frequently is becoming a hassle.

I've just setup the code like this...

```
using System.Diagnostics;

const bool TRACING_ENABLED = false;

//math math math....

Trace.WriteLineIf(TRACING_ENABLED, "Minimum Nitrogen Yield: " + minYieldNitrogen);
Trace.WriteLineIf(TRACING_ENABLED, "Minimum Water Yield: " + minYieldWater);
Trace.WriteLineIf(TRACING_ENABLED, "Minimum Seed Yield: " + minYieldSeed);

//more math math trace math trace math...
```

My question is... is this the best way to enable and disable tracing for debugging? These sorts of lines are scattered throughout the code, so I was hoping to not have to wrap blocks of `if` or whatever around them for housekeeping's sake.

Will the compiler optimize these lines out of the assembly since they are provided a constant of `false` at build time?

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) and a compiler flag to handle this instead.

This has the advantage of *completely removing the methods* from your production code - so the conditional check doesn't even occur.

Doing this, you could make your own method, such as:

```
[Conditional("TRACE")]
public WriteTraceLine(string message)
{
     Trace.WriteLine(message);
}
```

And then have a `TRACE` flag in your debug/non-production build settings.  This will cause the method to only exist in the compiled source (including the calls) when that flag is defined.

Comment: Can you do more definite conditionals like `[Conditional("TRACE = 1")]`?

Comment: My mistake actually... I had not done my homework yet on compiler symbols - they don't work this way.

Comment: @jocull Yeah - you can just use flags with ConditionalAttribute.  Note that the flag is also *case-sensitive*, which trips people up sometimes...

Comment: One pitfall I just ran into is that you have to put your `#define` in the file which contains your method calls - not your method definition. Other than that, this seems to be my favorite solution. Thank you.

Comment: @jocull It's typically better to just put it in your project settings as part of your build.  This allows you do handle this without changing defines - it can be a different build option in your .csproj

Comment: You can also define your symbols as parameters to the compiler. In that case, you don't have to modify your source at all, just compile using different parameters. If you're using Visual Studio, define your symbols in the project properties Build tab. Notice how "DEBUG" and "TRACE" symbols are represented by checkboxes there.

Comment: @jocull Under project settings->Build, there's a "Conditional Compilation symbols" where you can set any symbol you want defined for that specific configuration.  DEBUG/TRACE are handled for you, but you can make your own, as well.

Comment: Or just use the Debug class, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the Debug.WriteLine() method as well. All of the Debug methods use Reed's Conditional attribute, but instead based on the definition of a "DEBUG" constant (which you get for free in the default Debug build config and is absent in the default Release build config). The Debug methods use the same collection of Listeners that Trace does; the idea is that you use Trace.WriteLine() for anything you want to log or show in any build of the software, and Debug.WriteLine() for additional text you want to log or show in a Debug build of the software.

Comment: This is good, unless you need to do tracing in a release build for other purposes, at times.  Then rolling your own with your own constant (or just changing the constant) adds a lot of flexibility.

Comment: If you need tracing in a release build, take a look at TraceSource (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource).

Comment: I agree; if you need more than two levels of outputting (all the time and conditional on debug) then defining additional constants which can be used to control additional levels of trace output is great. You could create entire static classes similar in structure to Trace and Debug, like Verbose, that will use Trace behind the scenes but be conditional to a C-T constant like VERBOSE.

Comment: This is a great solution as well, but sometimes I need the tracing off when in `DEBUG` mode - it seems to really slow down processing when it's writing out to the console window.

Comment: Well, you can choose in the Build tab of the project properties not to define the DEBUG constant for any build config, even Debug (the name of the config is just that; you can make Debug builds produce code exactly like Release if you wanted). This will cause Debug writes not to occur, and so you can flip it off when you need a high-speed debuggable (non-optimized) run of the software, then turn it back on when you need logging. You can do the same thing with Trace and the TRACE constant (though understand that not all methods in the Trace class are conditional on this constant).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Trace.WriteLineIf(condition, message)`, use `Debug.WriteLine(message)`.

In a Debug build, calls to this method are compiled normally. In a release build, the compiler emits no code for the call, nor for parameter evaluation. If I understand your question correctly, this is exactly what you want.

To be precise, `Debug.WriteLine(message)` has a `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]` applied to it. As a result, the compiler will emit code for a call to it, if and only if the `DEBUG` symbol is defined during compilation. This symbol is defined in a standard Visual Studio Debug build, but not in a Release build.

For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you can do is to write your own class

```
public class MyTrace 
{
     [Conditional("TRACE")]
     public static void Trace(string message)
     {
          //trace code goes here
     }
     [Conditional("DEBUG")] 
     public static void Debug(string message)
     {
          //Debug code goes here
     }
}
```

The advantage of this is that you can either use the conditional compiling, add configuration logic or even use a logging package like Log4Net

Of course you would use it

```
  ....
  MyTrace.Trace(".....");
  MyTrace.Debug(".....");
  ....
```